# How to add support for PDF files with Vue Cli 3?

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, vue-cli

I need to configure Webpack to accept and handle PDF files with `url-loader` via the Vue Cli (latest).

**vue.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(pdf)(\?.*)?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              name: 'files/[name].[hash:8].[ext]'
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Does the above look correct or am I missing something? The docs on this are here: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/dev/docs/webpack.md#basic-configuration

I get the error:

> WebpackOptionsValidationError: Invalid configuration object. Webpack
>   has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match
>   the API schema. Configuration has an unknown property 'rules'.

I'm obviously missing something in my understanding here about how to augment the generated Webpack config in Vue.

Help appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out, I was missing another level for the `rules` array.

```
module: {}
```

So it should be in full:

```
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(pdf)(\?.*)?$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'url-loader',
              options: {
                name: 'files/[name].[hash:8].[ext]'
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

My bad! Hopefully this helps someone out there.

Comment: How exactly are you loading this? Using `<a href="@/assets/other/file.pdf">File Link</a>` doesn't seem to activate this loader.

Comment: Put it in the /public folder and and write download in your <a></a> tag

Answer (score 0):

For `coffeescript` and `vue-cli` version 3, I needed to `npm install -D coffee-loader` and then create this file as `vue.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.coffee$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'coffee-loader',
              options: {
                sourceMap: true
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```