# How to download a locally stored pdf in VueJS

Tags: pdf, vue.js

I have a single page application where I would like users to be able to download a locally stored pdf. However everything I try results in various errors.

Here is a link to a very similar problem...
[How to download a locally stored file in VueJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48015954/how-to-download-a-locally-stored-file-in-vuejs)

However as I'm using vue cli 3, I do not have the webpack.config file and of course I'm trying to download a pdf, not a csv (hence why I can't use the solution to his question)

```
├──app
│  └──Views
│     └──page1.vue
└──assets
      └──example.pdf
```

In page1.vue I have this line:

```
<a v-bind:href="item.loc" download>{{item.title}}</a>
```

And in the export I have this line

```
data() {
  return {
    item: {title: 'Download PDF', 
loc: require('../static/example.pdf')}
}
```

However this method returns this error...

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
(Source code omitted for this binary file)

I can't seem to find a 'PDF Loader' unfortunately.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add support for PDF files with Vue Cli 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49067696/how-to-add-support-for-pdf-files-with-vue-cli-3)

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work... I added the script to my config.vue.js but it still doesn't seem to activate this loader.  I get the same error.

Comment: Please update your question